# how to publish the same node on different laptops under one master node

Tags: ros, multi-robot, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Here is my setup.
I have a multi-robot task where i setup an ad-hoc network and set the master uri to one of the 3 laptops. 2 laptops on the 2 robots and 1 laptop is in the middle.  I have 2 icreate robots which will run the non-master nodes.
For basic coordination, i defined a custom message with 2 fields where the master node running laptop listens  the robot id and their states. the laptops on the robots will be running the same node to publish their id and state. However, as there is one master node , the same node cannot be run on the laptops. I can guess that i should do something like  group namespacing.
any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43794/how-to-publish-the-same-node-on-different-laptops-under-one-master-node/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the nodes can publish on the same topic and just equal node names are your problem, you can use anonymous node names. In a launch file, you can use `$(anon foo)` as node name. Otherwise, you can pass the `AnonymousName` option.

If you need separate topics, you will have to use groups in launch files. Either use different launch files and just include your actual launch file inside a group with a namespace set or you might be able to use an environment variable. For instance, the following might work:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="$(env ROBOT_NAME)">
    ...
  </group>
</launch>
```

By setting the environment variable ROBOT_NAME to different names, the nodes should then publish on different namespaces.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3